# sinon spy to check if func is called is always returning false though the function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon, sinon-chai

I am testing javascript application, though the function is called function always complains it is never called.

Here is the code snippet and test

**test.spec.js**

```js
const Aupdate = require('../accountsUpdate');

it.only('should check if function is called or not', function(done) {
  let reqUpdateAccount = {
    body: {
      Account: 'newAccount1'
    }
  };
  let spy = sinon.spy(Aupdate, 'getUpdateArgs');
  Aupdate.accountsUpdate(reqUpdateAccount, res);
  expect(spy).to.have.been.called; //test fails
  done();
});
```

**file.js**

```
function getUpdateArgs (Request) {
  console.log("func called);
 }

function accountsUpdate(req, res) {
 let args = getUpdateArgs(req.body);// function spied is called here
 ...
}
```

Comment: Are you using jest to testing?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

`index.ts`:

```js
function getUpdateArgs(Request) {
  console.log('func called');
}

function accountsUpdate(req, res) {
  let args = exports.getUpdateArgs(req.body);
}

exports.getUpdateArgs = getUpdateArgs;
exports.accountsUpdate = accountsUpdate;
```

`index.spec.ts`:

```js
import { expect } from 'chai';
import sinon from 'sinon';

const Aupdate = require('./');

it.only('should check if function is called or not', function() {
  let reqUpdateAccount = {
    body: {
      Account: 'newAccount1'
    }
  };
  const res = {};
  let spy = sinon.spy(Aupdate, 'getUpdateArgs');
  Aupdate.accountsUpdate(reqUpdateAccount, res);
  expect(spy.calledWith({ Account: 'newAccount1' })).to.be.true;
  sinon.assert.calledOnce(spy);
});
```

Unit test result:

```sh
func called
  ✓ should check if function is called or not

  1 passing (7ms)
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/mocha-chai-sinon-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/57997682